# Can't boot after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, boot, 12.10

after installing 3 days ago Ubuntu 12.04, today I was asked to upgrade to 12.10. I did it and after rebooting, I have the purple screen of ubuntu for a second, and then I got a black one permanently.

I have tried to do as it is said here [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078) and to reinstall the nvida driver (apt-get install nvida-current) but it is still the same.

Any suggestion?